# Ejecutar funcion despues de que termine el bucle

Tags: nodejs

Tengo un problema en nodejs, estoy usando el modulo http para crear un servicio web donde se muestran los status de un servidor de videojuego. Lo que pasa es que la función para detectar min/max jugadores tarda en obtener los resultos y esto afecta ya que solo me esta imprimiendo un valor o nulo ya que la variable inicial es nula. Espero me puedan ayudar en este problema. La función ping es la que obtiene los datos y es por socket, tiene limite máximo de 3000.

```
function onRequest(request, response) 
{
    response.writeHead(200,{"Content-type" : "text/html"});
    body = HTML_RESPONSE_CLEAR.replace("[NETWORK_NAME_JSON]",Config.networ_name);
    var AllServers = Object.keys(Servers);
    AllServers.forEach(function(objKey)
    {
        var cards = '';
        value = Servers[objKey];
        ping(value.ip, value.port, function(err, res) {
            if (err) {
                var card = HTML_CARD_OFFLINE+"\n";
                playing = 0;
                maxPlayers = 0;
                card = card.replace('[SERVER_NAME_JSON]',value.name);
                card = card.replace('[IP_PORT_INFO_JSON]',value.ip + ' : ' + value.port);
                card = card.replace('[SCORE_PLAYER_PLAYING_JSON]',playing+' : '+maxPlayers);
                card = card.replace('[CARD_LEVEL_STATUS]', getScoreValue(maxPlayers,playing));
                cards = cards + card;
            } else {
                playing = res.currentPlayers;
                maxPlayers = res.maxPlayers;
                if(playing == maxPlayers)
                {
                    var card = HTML_CARD_FULL+"\n";
                } else {
                    var card = HTML_CARD_ONLINE+"\n";
                }
                card = card.replace('[SERVER_NAME_JSON]',value.name);
                card = card.replace('[IP_PORT_INFO_JSON]',value.ip + ' : ' + value.port);
                card = card.replace('[SCORE_PLAYER_PLAYING_JSON]',playing+' : '+maxPlayers);
                card = card.replace('[CARD_LEVEL_STATUS]', getScoreValue(maxPlayers,playing));
                cards = cards + card;
            }
        }, 3000);
    })
        body = body.replace('[HTML_CARDS]',cards);
        response.write(body);
        response.end();
}
```

Comment: Bienvenido al mundo [AJAX](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/AJAX).

Comment: ping devuelve una promesa?

Comment: Tienes que usar observables o promesas, que te devuelve la funcion ping? si es una llamada http normalmente se devuelve una promesa, sino deberías crear un observable y actuar cuando finalice el resultado de la llamada

Comment: Ping devuelve un JSON o un string de error